# Trying to send info to my database from a select tag

Tags: php, html, sql, select, drop-down-menu

Been trying to get this PHP to send to my database but for some reason it won't work but it isn't giving me any errors either. The code probably isn't the prettiest only been working on PHP for 6 months so any help is much appreciated.

```html
                <form method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Send Message to: </label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="slectrecipient" name="recipient">
                           <?php 
                           include("conn.php");

                           $info = "SELECT FirstName, SecondName, id FROM PT_accounts WHERE NOT id='$accountid'";
                           $result4 = $conn->query($info);
                           if(!$result4){
                               echo $conn->error;
                           }
                           while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()){
                               $recipientfirst = $row4['FirstName'];
                               $recipientsecond = $row4['SecondName'];
                               $recipientid = $row4['id'];

                               echo "<option value='$recipientid'> $recipientfirst $recipientsecond</option>";
                           }
                           
                           if(isset($_POST['messagetext'])){
                                $currentdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                                $messagetext = $_POST['messagetext'];
                                $recipid = $_POST['recipient'];
                                
                                echo $currentdate;
                                echo $messagetext;
                                echo $recipid;
                               $messageinsert = "INSERT INTO PT_Messages (SenderID, RecipientID, Date, Message) 
                               VALUES ('$accountid', '$recipid', '$currentdate', '$messagetext') ";


                               $result5 = $conn->query($messageinsert);

                               if(!$result5){
                                   echo $conn->error;
                               }else{
                                   echo "<p> $messageinsert</p>";
                                   echo "<p>Message Sent!</p>";
                               }
                           }

                           ?>
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Message :</label>
                        <text class="form-control" id="messagetext" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Send">
                </form>
```

I know there's two `$row` and `$result`s but I've altered these in my actual to be different so I know that's not the issue. I'm unsure if it's the select tag with the option value that isn't written correctly. Or if I have to somehow set the dropdown menu selection as a PHP variable to then be sent to the database?

Comment: Is there a `<select></select>` somewhere for your `<option>`s?

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize the query

Comment: fixed it to show the <select></select>

Comment: Can you show the form? Also does the DB record write with an empty value or there is no `insert` being executed?

Comment: Fixed to show the whole form, and the database doesnt allow empty values, anytime ive executed the code the database remains empty

Comment: You have nothing `name`d `messagetext`. See `<text class="form-control" **id**="messagetext" rows="3">`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user3783243

I didn't name the textarea but had set it as an id.

```html
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="messagetext" id="messageid" rows="3">
```

I had it as id="messagetext"